# How we can redirect to user profile page from any page and redirect back to previous page using JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, redirect, delve

This question may sound technically funny, but I actually want to know.

Can we redirect user to his/her delv profile page in SharePoint Online and after redirection, again redirect to previous page automatically?

I want to achieve this via JavaScript.

Comment: How are you going to add JS to the Profile Page?

Comment: That's the main point. It seems illogical requirement, But I thought there would some query string or any other way.